# VIM question about the colorize plugin

Tags: vim, plugins, colorize

It is working well but it relies on my using <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get out of input mode.

I tend to use <kbd>jj</kbd> (which i set up in -vimrc)

How do I adjust the last line of the code to suit <kbd>jj</kbd>?

"You need the next line to change the color back when you hit escape.

```
inoremap <Esc> <Esc>:highlight Normal guibg=Sys_Window<cr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following mapping in your **~/.vimrc**:

```
inoremap jj <Esc>:highlight Normal guibg=Sys_Window<CR>
```

**Note**: If you have a `inoremap jj <Esc>` line already, you could subsitute the `inoremap` for just `imap` -- that way, the `jj` just 'falls through' and also uses your `<Esc>` bind that you set up.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is an event that is launched when you exit insert mode. Maybe you should better use it:

```
augroup alterNormal
    autocmd InsertLeave * :highlight Normal guibg=Sys_Window
augroup END
```